# Is the axiom of regularity/foundation equivalent to $\forall x:x\notin x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axioms, foundations

In set theory, the [axiom of regularity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Axiom_of_regularity#) can be used to [prove](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Axiom_of_regularity#/No_set_is_an_element_of_itself)

$$
\tag{*}\label{*}
\forall x:x\notin x.
$$

Can the direction be reversed, i.e., can $(\ref{*})$ prove regularity in ZF$\setminus$R?

By ZF$\setminus$R I mean the standard axioms of ZF, without the axiom of regularity. Stated differently, as in the title, is $(\ref{*})$ equivalent to the axiom of regularity in ZF$\setminus$R?

Comment: It's not equivalent, since (I believe) it is consistent that sets $x,y$ such that $x\in y\in x$ exist, which still fails regularity (the set $\{x,y\}$ would have no $\in$-minimal element).

Comment: @Vsotvep But you still have to argue that the remaining $\mathsf{ZF}$-axioms can't build a self-containing set from such an $x,y$. (I think that is in fact the case, but it isn't quite immediate.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed, I think I've read something like this before, but I can't find where and don't remember why...

Comment: The axiom of extensionality on its own does not prevent having $x\ne y$ with $x=\{y\}$ and $y=\{x\}$, but the other axioms require having so many sets in any model that it's a difficult job to show that if ZF is consistent then even such a minimal quirk has a model.

Comment: Here is a simple construction: Let $(V,\in)$ be a model of ZF and then let $F:V\to V$ be the permutation swapping $\emptyset$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and leaving everything else fixed. Then let $E$ be the relation on $V$ defined by $xEy$ if and only if $x\in F(y).$ $(V,E)$ is a model of ZF-R (this part requires a little work... cf "Rieger-Bernays permuation model") and in $(V,E),$ we have  $\emptyset \;E\;\{\emptyset\}\;E\;\emptyset$ and there are no sets with $x E x.$